# Span of a set of k points in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, span

I'm trying to understand the following proof:

> Given k points $p_1,...,p_k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then (for all $i,j =1,...,k$):
>
> $$p_i+\text{span}(p_1-p_i,...,p_k-p_i)=p_j+\text{span}(p_1-p_j,...,p_k-p_j)$$

The proof starts like this:

> Since $p_l-p_j=(p_l-p_i)-(p_j-p_i)$ for all $l,i,j=1,...,k$, it's true that $\text{span}(p_1-p_i,...,p_k-p_i)=\text{span}(p_1-p_j,...,p_k-p_j)$

How do you get to this conclusion? I understand that in this context $l$ varies and $i,j$ are set so on the left side of the equation there's a certain vector for each $l$ and on the right side you have a different vector for each $l$ plus a set vector that's the same for each $l$.
But I just don't see why you get to this conclusion.

Comment: To get (=parameterize) a linear manifold you need a) to move to *any* point on the manifold (that's what $p_i$ is doing) plus b) to move from that point arbitrarily along the manifold (that's what span is doing).

Comment: I sort of understand this lemma intuitively but it's the given proof I'm having trouble with, thanks for the intuition though!

Comment: The first formula after "Since" means that the three vectors are *linearly dependent*, so the pairs when $i$ is fixed span the same subspace as the pairs when $j$ is fixed. The easiest is to take three points $p_1,p_2,p_3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the plane that goes through it to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $v_l=p_l-p_i$ and $w_l=p_l-p_j$. The equation
$$
p_l-p_j=(p_l-p_i)-(p_j-p_i)\tag1
$$
just means that $w_l=v_l-v_j$ which gives
$$
\text{span}\{w_k\}\subset\text{span}\{v_k\}.\tag2
$$
On the other hand, the equation $(1)$ is $w_l=v_l+w_i$, i.e. $v_l=w_l-w_i$ which gives
$$
\text{span}\{v_k\}\subset\text{span}\{w_k\}.\tag3
$$
Combine $(2)$ and $(3)$ to get the conclusion.